# How to Visualize the crystal planes of calcite?

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

I've been struggling to visualize the structure of calcite. Most papers say it grows in a rhombohedron capped by (104) faces. However, I don't see why it would do this when looking at it using CrystalMaker
[image: calcite unit cell with 104 vector in green]

Can one, by looking at the unit cell, discern which crystal faces will be expressed? How?

Comment: Why crystals grow the way that they do is still a mystery. Calcite crystals of visual size have grown into more than 300 different forms of crystal structures.